# Differences between daily-live and daily-canary Ubuntu images

Tags: daily-build

On [cdimage.ubuntu.com](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/) there are two versions of Hirsute Hippo.

I know that both are test versions released daily, but I can't find any information about the differences between the two.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I'd join the chat and join #ubuntu-devel to ask there. Someone there will almost certainly know.

Comment: @KGill Thank you for your helpful suggestion.

Comment: I see this question has been asked more than year ago?, @user186255 did you able to found the answer? {As i am also looking for the same}

Comment: @Aravinth, the *canary* is a label used for a special purposes related to testing. It's not always been used by the new Ubuntu Desktop installer, and won't always be... but that's still it's current use though it's *kinetic* currently - https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-canary/current/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reading going to the initial source for topics like this, which is usually found on the Ubuntu Community Hub.  ie.

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/new-desktop-installer-preview-build/24765

> As part of our continued work to refresh the Ubuntu Desktop Installer,
> we’re releasing an alternate preview build of Impish Indri that enables users to test the latest implementation.
>
> The new installer has been developed in [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) and builds on the hard work of the Yaru team to ensure it integrates seamlessly with the Ubuntu desktop style.
>
> You can read more of the background behind the new installer [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/refreshing-the-ubuntu-desktop-installer/20659)

Yes *development* on this started awhile ago now (*hirsute* cycle), it was hoped to be ready last release (*impish*), then *jammy*, but it's improving and is expected to be offered as an alternate ISO, even possibly an *alternate* installer on the primary desktop ISO for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (*jammy*)

The *canary* ISO just provides the alternate installer.